# Kettle client to invoke EJBs deployed in JBoss

Tags: ejb, client, jboss5.x, pentaho, kettle

I'm just starting with **Kettle** (PDI). 
I want to know if it is possible to **deploy EJB3 in JBoss AS 5.1.0**, and then invoke EJBs from a **remote client through KETTLE** by using the JNDI API to first lookup the bean proxy and then invoke on that proxy?

Basically, I want to extract, transform and load data that was deployed to the application server through Kettle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you'd like to implement a normal stand-alone remote EJB client. This client is to be integrated into an (open source) ETL tool.

I would be very surprised if this does not work. If you managed to have a stand-alone remote client (sometimes tough enough), there could be one problem: Conflicting libraries: Normally a JBoss clients use `jboss-client.jar`, and its content may conflict with libraries provided by Kettle. But Kettle is open source, so with a little effort you could resolve this as well.